# Adapting Regular Expression in Django URL to match filepath

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, django-urls

So I am currently working on a web application that takes as input the location of a malware file for one of the functions.

This is passed via the views file. However after some altering of the models section of the application I found it was unable to parse the full filepath.

The code below works for the following pcap as input:

8cdddcd3-35fa-468d-8647-816518a9836a435be1c6e904836ad65f97f3eac4cbe19ee7ba0da48178fc7f00206270469165.pcap

```
         url(r'^analyse/(?P<pcap>[\w\-]+\.pcap)$', views.analyse, name='analyse'),
```

However this code no longer works when it is a pcap containing the full filepath.

/home/freddie/malwarepcaps/8cdddcd3-35fa-468d-8647-816518a9836a435be1c6e904836ad65f97f3eac4cbe19ee7ba0da48178fc7f00206270469165.pcap

Any suggestions or pointers on how exactly I would alter the regular expression to accomodate the full filepath in the string being passed to the route would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would say send this through post unless you need it for SEO or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex: `((/\w+?)+/)?([\w-]+\.pcap)`

django regex: `^analyse(?P<pcap>((/\w+?)+/)?([\w-]+\.pcap))$`

note that there is no slash after `analyse` because it's part of `pcap` now.

so `analyse/home/freddie/malwarepcaps/foo-bar.pcap` should match this pattern and `pcap` will be equal to `/home/freddie/malwarepcaps/foo-bar.pcap`

test:

https://pythex.org/?regex=((%2F%5Cw%2B%3F)%2B%2F)%3F(%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B%5C.pcap)&test_string=8cdddcd3-35fa-468d-8647-816518a9836a435be1c6e904836ad65f97f3eac4cbe19ee7ba0da48178fc7f00206270469165.pcap%20%0A%2Fhome%2Ffreddie%2Fmalwarepcaps%2F8cdddcd3-35fa-468d-8647-816518a9836a435be1c6e904836ad65f97f3eac4cbe19ee7ba0da48178fc7f00206270469165.pcap&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

PS: I think it's better to move such parameter (path - `/home/f/m/f.pcap`) into querystring (for GET request) or into http-body (for POST request)
so it will be easier to obtain param without url-matching

Comment: This site pythex seems very useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Reverse for 'analyse' with keyword arguments '{'pcap': {}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['analyse/((/\\w+?)+/)?([\\w-]+\\.pcap)']
 - however this error seems to persist

Comment: with the new url pattern - url(r'^analyse/((/\w+?)+/)?([\w-]+\.pcap)', views.analyse, name='analyse'),

Comment: i showed you only regex, you need to add django specific  key `?P<pcap>` so django understand how this url param named: `'^analyse?P<pcap>((/\w+?)+/)?([\w-]+\.pcap)$'`

Comment: @dipl0 i updated my answer. also check the postscript